# Reading inputs in java

Tags: java, user-input

```
import java.io.*;
public class inputting {
/**
* @param args
* @throws IOException 
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("number??");
String str;
     int i=0;
    while (i<5) {
            str=br.readLine();
            int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
            System.out.println(n);
        i++;}
}
```

}

if i want to read 5 integers how do i do that? what extra code i need to write?

Comment: Think about using a "loop" such as a for loop if you know in advance how many ints you want the user to add, or a do-while loop if you don't.  Also, you might want to consider formatting that code with appropriate indentations, cowboy.

Comment: On the same line or different lines?

Comment: @Amir Raminfar  what edits do i need on this code.?

Comment: @Karan: the edits you need are to use a loop as has been suggested many many times in the answers below and in my comment above. Give it a try, you won't be disappointed.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Fuels it says str cannot be resolved, i guess i need to define str before or something else?

Comment: @Karan: If you don't show us the updated code causing the error, we can't help you.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels edits saved.

Comment: If you *know in advance* that you want to read 5 ints, then do what I recommended in my first comment.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels its not even letting me enter numbers. it just prints number?? and does not let me enter any.? Edits saved.

Comment: I guess I need to spell it out more: What I said in my first comment was "[use a loop] such as a ***for loop*** if you know in advance how many ints you want the user to add".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use a Java Scanner to read inputs.

To your existing code, assuming `String  str = br.readLine();` makes str contain the line of at least one integer, eg. "10 20 30 40 50"

What you need to do is:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
While (sc.hasNext())
{
   System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
   // ...or assign it to an array elment...your choice!
}
```

Comment: i know but how do i use the loops for dividing that string into integers?

Comment: @Karan: that comment makes no sense. If you're using Scanner, the input already is in int form.

Comment: It's called string tokenisation, and that's precisely the whole point of the Java Scanner class - to abstract away the work for you.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  i am not using scanner, using the same code.

Comment: @evandrix how do i tokenize it.. plz help?

Comment: read: the Java Scanner class already performs that functionality for you implicitly, otherwise check out [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask multiple times the question `number??` you just need to use a `for` or `while` loop around these three lines:

```
System.out.println("number??");
String  str = br.readLine();
int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

and add the read numbers to a list so you'd just need to change the last line.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your readline in a while loop that checks for user input to quit

```
        while ( !(str = br.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
            System.out.println(n);
        }
```